# Connecting to SignalR from Chrome extension - error: method could not be resolved

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm building an Chrome extension that will interact with a SignalR HUB.

The HUB is working fine with my local files which were created with the proxy connection. However, I can't use the proxy connection in the chrome extension because it's not in the same project so I had to define it myself:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:61xxx/signalr/hubs', {useDefaultPath: false});
var roomIndexHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('roomIndexHub');
```

This works fine, and if I use a breakpoint on the server `OnConnected` method it does fire, and I also see that the log which says the connection was established. But when I try to run my own functions, I get this error (on client-side):

> SignalR: 'test' method could not be resolved. No method found with that name.     at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.NullMethodDescriptor.b__0(IHub
>   emptyHub, Object[] emptyParameters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.Incoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext
>   context)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAwaiterHelper.PreserveCultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubPipelineModule.<>c__DisplayClass1.<b__0>d__3.MoveNext().
>
> SignalR:
>   roomindexhub.test failed to execute. Error: 'test' method could not be
>   resolved. No method found with that name.

This is my client side code:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:61xxx/signalr/hubs', {useDefaultPath: false});
var roomIndexHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('roomIndexHub');

connection.logging = true;
connection.start().done(function() {
    // Wire up Send button to call RoomIndexHubProxy on the server.
    console.log('Hub has started');
    $("#signalr").click(function(){
        roomIndexHubProxy.invoke('test');
    });

});

connection.error(function (error) {
    console.log('SignalR error: ' + error)
});
```

server side code (although very simple):

```
public class RoomIndexHub : Hub
    {
        public RoomIndexHub(){}

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            return base.OnConnected();  // this works!
        }

        internal void test()
        {
            int i = 0;   // this doesn't work
        }
    }   
}
```

As I'm writing those lines I see this `at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.NullMethodDescriptor.b__0(IHub

> emptyHub, Object[] emptyParameters)`.

However I dunno why this is happening since I did define:

`var roomIndexHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('roomIndexHub');`

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: `Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly` - in other words inaccessible externally. Although I don't know any c#.

Comment: oh sigh this was so easy.. sometimes u need to know where to look I guess...
I was so focused on the client side for this error that I missed that simple thing.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) for `internal` keyword says:

> Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly

In other words, inaccessible externally, so simply remove `internal`.